# Smooth animation

Tags: animation, graph-editor

I am doing animation of the dolphin's tale and can't make it smooth. It goes up smoothly and then just drops down to the required position from frame 40 to frame 41. The graph looks good. Any ideas what is wrong?

[image: 40 frame]

[image: 41 frame]

Comment: Tip for looping animations in frame constricted timeline. Copy the first frame and paste it on the end, then move it one frame outside of the play range. This should help remove the strange movement.